# ML a real list return a real number

Tags: list, sml, ml, real-number

I am currently working on a ML small project and learning how to work with it, but here are some problems that I'm facing but cannot find any source online.

I want to have a function to return the last number of the list, which is a real number list. I wrote a code to return a single element real list, but i will it to be a real number but not a list. here is my code:

```
fun last [] = nil
  | last(head::nil) = [head]
  | last(head::list) = last(list)
```

I thought

```
last(head::nil)=head
```

would help get the real number but it just give me an error that:

```
operator domain: 'Z list list
operand:         real list
```

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is the first clause, `last [] = nil`. `nil` is not a real number.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @melpomene: Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As melpomene says, `nil` isn't a value of type *real*, so it can't be the return type for the empty list. In fact, *no value* can be returned, because the list is empty! This makes the function `last` partial. You want to [avoid partial functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Avoiding_partial_functions), because they may crash at runtime. You can define an alternative function, `lastOpt`:

```
fun lastOpt [] = NONE
  | lastOpt [x] = SOME x
  | lastOpt (_::xs) = lastOpt xs
```

For example,

```
- lastOpt [1,2,3];
> val it = SOME 3 : int option
- lastOpt [];
> val it = NONE : 'a option
```

This passes responsibility for handling empty lists explicitly to the caller of `lastOpt`.

The built-in function `List.last` was made unsafely with exceptions:

```
fun last [] = raise Empty
  | last [x] = x
  | last (_::xs) = last xs
```

I wouldn't recommend using this.